# How do I work out how many people would be selected into a specific age range by chance?

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling

I have a sample of children that are aged 5 years up to 7 years. In total there are 2000 children from 160 centres. The purpose of this exercise was to give each child an assessment and record the result.

Two sub-groups had a higher chance of selection than the rest of the children:

- children age 5 years and 11 months to 6 years and 1 month
- children who were within three weeks of starting at the centre when the assessment took place

I need to work out how many children would have been selected into the above groups, if they hadn't had a higher chance of selection (or, how much to weight the results of the children in these groups by to account for the higher chance of selection).

So more specifically, if I sampled 10 children aged 5 to 7 years from each of 160 centres, how many would be aged 5 years and 11 months to 6 years and 1 month, by chance? And how many would be within their first three weeks of starting at the centre?

I'm assuming that the distribution of ages in the population of 5 to 7 year olds is uniform.

Comment: We can't answer this question without knowing a bit more about the population. Eg age distribution and what have you. Do you assume all ages have about the same population?

Comment: I assume that overall the distribution of ages is uniform (birth dates in a population are not - the age distribution of these children would likely reflect that).

Answer (score 0):

Let the entire population have size $N$. Let $N_*$ be the population satisfying some criteria (eg. between 5 years and 11 months to 6 years and 1 month).

Suppose you sample $n$ from your population of $N$, and of your sample a total of $n_*$ come from the subpopulation $N_*$. Then this problem can be reduced to a simple binomial distribution problem.

You have $n$ trials, and each trial has probability of success $\frac{N_*}{N}$. Hence the probability of getting $n_*$ children from your sample is simply

$$P = {n \choose n_*} \frac{N_*}{N}^{n_*} \left(1-\frac{N_*}{N} \right)^{n-n_*}$$

Similarly, the probability of getting at least $n_*$ is

$$P = \sum_{k=n_*}^n {n \choose k} \frac{N_*}{N}^{k} \left(1-\frac{N_*}{N} \right)^{n-k}$$

Note that the binomial distribution assumes independent trials which is not strictly true here, since you're sampling without replacement. However, if the population as a hole is large, this dependence is negligible.

Hence to work out the probability you only need to estimate $N_*$. If you assume age distribution is uniform, then this is fairly straightforward, though non-uniform birthdates complicates it.

Comment: What's your opinion on ignoring non-uniform birthdates? Would the impact be negligible?

Comment: Yes. The [distribution of birthdates seems almost uniform](https://www.panix.com/~murphy/bday.html). The variation doesn't seem that big. You could adjust by assuming uniform age distribution by year, and then assign each month its own probability based on what you know of the age distribution. But it does not seem significant to me.